# How to get grouped product ID from purchased or cart product

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm using grouped products to track promotions. Simple products will at times belong to multiple grouped products, so checking parentProductIds is of no use. I'm wondering how to track the grouped product ID when a product is purchased through the grouped (promotion) SKU. I can see it's being stored in info_buyRequest and super_product_config within the orders, but how do I get that information back out? And is there a way to get it out in the cart/quote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get it with the following code in cart.phtml, in the foreach($this->getItems() as $_item):

```
$values = unserialize($_item->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest')->getValue());
$parentId = $values['super_product_config']['product_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want to get this information, you could get it after a checkout process when the sales is saved. Then you could use the events `sales_order_save_after` and create a method in a class to get the items of a grouped product. 
What is important here is the object of a class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item` which has information about the product and the parents of a product
Here is an example:

```
public function processSalesOrder($observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getOrder()
    $quoteItems = $order->getItemsCollection(null, true);

    /*@var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item */
    foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {

        $parent = $item->getParentItem();
        if(!is_null($parent)){
           // do your stuff - you have a product parent which has children product
           // $item is the children
           echo 'The parent product is ' . $parent->getSku();
           echo 'One of the children product is' .$item->getSku();
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work. It gets to the foreach, but $parent is null.

Answer (score 0):

On cart page grouped product is treated as a simple product. In Magento 2 you can get the parent id of these simple products from session. This worked for me:

```
<?php 

$catalogSession = $_SESSION['catalog'];             
$parentId = $catalogSession['last_viewed_product_id'];

?>
```